# I added pods to an existing file, and it made another project in my workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, workspace

I added pods to an existing workspace and now I have 2 of the same project in my workspace (Both projects ending in IOS). If I delete either one, I lose all references to the project.

Here is what the project tree looks like and the pods file. Anyone have any insight?

[image]

Comment: whenever you add some other pods, just use update pods command. You don't have to install everytime.

Comment: ok, does that explain why it duplicated my IOS project?

Comment: whenever you install pods it will create workspace for it.

Comment: Right but I already had a workspace... is there a way to not create a new workspace?

Comment: Delete the old work space, deleting old workspace will not create any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the podfile should be

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demo8' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.16'    

end
```

This is no requirement to specify workspace externally until there is any requirements.